# ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller error - AS

Tags: actionscript-3, displayobject, removechild

I have this code snippet inside a function that checks if an object exists on stage and removes it:

```
public function closeContent(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    removeChild(txt);
    removeChild(ldr.content);
    removeChild(_closeButton);
    container_mc.visible = false;
    statusText.text="";
    if (contains(submitButton)) {
        removeChild(submitButton);
    }
    if (contains(saveinfoButton)) {
        removeChild(saveinfoButton);
    }
}
```

I tried to change `stage` with `this` and `root` but always get this error `ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller`

Comment: It would help readers a lot if you formatted the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error signals that you are trying to remove a `DisplayObject` with `removeChild` that apparently is not a child of the `DisplayObjectContainer` this code is executed from.

One way to solve this problem is to check if the object you are trying to remove is actually a child of the container using `contains`. You are doing this for some of the objects you are removing (`submitButton` and `saveinfoButton`), but not for some others.

Try wrapping the `removeChild` calls for `txt`, `ldr.content` and `_closeButton` in if statements that use `contains` to check whether these `DisplayObject`s are in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(txt);  
e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(ldr.content)  
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function closeContent(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    removeChild(txt);
    removeChild(ldr.content);
    removeChild(_closeButton);
    container_mc.visible = false;
    statusText.text="";
    if (contains(submitButton)) {
        removeChild(submitButton);
        removeChild(saveinfoButton);
    }
}
```

You may be able to add both items for removal in the conditional with &&:

```
    if (contains(submitButton && saveinfoButton)) {
```